# Summing cotangent pairs

Tags: summation, trigonometric-series

I've stumbled across an identity that I think holds, but can't prove it. The identity is:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \cot(\phi_i - \phi_{i+1}) \cot(\phi_i - \phi_{i-1}) = -1
$$

The angles $\phi_i$ are some arbitrary set of angles, with the only constraint being that $\phi_i - \phi_{i+1}$ does not equal $0$ or $\pi$. Addition of the indices is modular, so that $\phi_{N+1} = \phi_{1}$.

The formula comes from some normalisation conditions in quantum mechanics, and it arose while checking a result that I've derived otherwise, which is my reason for believing it stands. It can be shown straightforwardly using Hermite's cotangent identity if $N=3$, but I'm unable to generalise further.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't hold for $N\neq 3$.

Comment: Did you check this in Mathematica? I'll check the origin calculation where this came up and maybe see what the result is for N=4

Comment: Did *you* check it? For $N=4$ and $\phi_i=i\pi/4$, the sum is equal to $\color{red}{-4}$.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased badly. I meant to say "did you get the result that it doesn't hold in general using mathematica". I looked at the original calculation and there's an assumption in jumping to the N>3 case that maybe doesn't hold, but I still think the LHS series will be needed at some point... I'll investigate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to see what you get for $N=2$ yet? Both terms of the sum on the left side are equal.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_cotangent_identity

Does this Wikipedia article answer your question?

Comment: I can use that for N=3, but not for higher N